# Facebook Login Swift UI granting permissions

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swiftui, facebook-login

I have a swiftUI function that is successfully logging in to facebook, but only if the permissions are just publicProfile and email, if I add any other permissions like the following

```
loginManager.logIn(permissions: [.publicProfile, .email, .user_friends], viewController: nil) { loginResult in
```

Then I get the following error: `Type Array<Permission>.ArrayLiteralElement (aka Permission) has no member user_friends`

I've tested with several different permissions in [facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_friends).
What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe it's `.userFriends` rather? I mean if "public_profile" became `. publicProfile`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue does seem to be that the names should be written in camelcase like publicProfile or userFriends. However for some of the other permissions I was using, specifically manage_fundraisers, there isn't an option for it directly as manageFundraisers. For anyone else with that issue I was able to solve it by using

```
.custom("manage_fundraisers")
```